# Make the navbar slide down when scrolling like in Apple iphone 5c page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a web page based Bootstrap 3 and I like to make my navbar slide down when scrolling down like in the Apple [iPhone 5c Page](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/), (**havbar should be hidden initialy**) I', not an expert in js and any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Hear is a sample code I have created. [CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/j8MLoKkYAzrgC4cHhCQb)

Comment: Recreate your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ please.

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the `scroll` event  of the window :

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    // here the bar is id'ed myBar
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) { // choose the value you want.
        $('#myBar:hidden').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('#myBar:visible').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Make sure the CSS is correct : `position:fixed`, and so on ...

Here is a [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MYALJ/)